# Extract value from text field to support GROUP BY in SQL from Redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table that essentially contains survey results that I'm trying to do some statistical analysis on (example data at end of question).  For the purposes of this question we can assume the table has three columns: `response`, `date_submitted` and `meta_data`

The `response` column contains a simple `1` or `0`.  The `timestamp` is the datetime when the survey was submitted.  And the `meta_data` field is essentially a CSV text field with a list of key, value pairs.

Example row below

```
f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=<someTemplateId>, ...
```

Most of this data I don't care about but the `templateId` is the value I want to pull out of `meta_data`.  I would like to use `templateId` to `GROUP BY` all my rows so I can get summary statistics for each `templateId`.  Long term this value should be extracted into its own column but given time constraints I am unable to update our data generating process for this and need to perform the analysis before that work can be done

Ultimatley the query I'd like to be able to do is

```sql
SELECT sum(response) FROM my_table GROUP BY <template_id>
```

Example Data

```
   reponse                    meta_data                  timestamp
0        0  f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=77 2021-04-07 09:51:55.655793
1        0  f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=55 2021-04-07 08:51:55.655793
2        1  f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=77 2021-04-07 07:51:55.655793
3        1  f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=77 2021-04-07 06:51:55.655793
4        1  f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=66 2021-04-07 05:51:55.655793
```

To clarify the above... `f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=77` is the entry for `meta_data` in the first row

Comment: Your sample data is a bit confusing, The header shows three columns, but it seems that one row has at least four columns (if not 6 in case `f1=v1` is a single column value as well)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is a redshift cluster.  I've updated my answer and tags to indicate this.  Regarding the test data, one column was originally poorly named, I've updated it to be `meta_data`.  And while it doesn't render well in text `f1=v1, f2=v2, templateId=77` is one entry in that column

Comment: You realise that COUNT() treats 1s and 0s equally? Count of 0,1,0,1 is 4?

Comment: @MatBailie ah you're right, sorry that should be a sum, will update

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html):

```
select t.*,
       regexp_substr(meta_data, 'template_id=([^ ]+) ', 1, 1, 'e') as template_id
from t;
```

Comment: Quick question on your solution.  If `templateId` is a string would it still work?  This wasn't well demonstrated in my original question but some of the IDs are numeric and some are strings ex. `templateId=someTemplateId`

Comment: @sedavidw . . . `template_id` *is* a string.  In any case, it is returning all characters up to a space.

Comment: Well to be clear we would only want until the `,` not the space.  But either way this solution doesn't appear to be working for me as `templateId` is always coming back as empty

Comment: @sedavidw . . . Arrg!  The regular expression was missing the `[]`.